# Creating new polars dataframe column based on other column

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a hard time with what should be a very common use case on polars dataframes.
I simply want to create a new column on an existing dataframe based on some other column.
Here is the code I try, but doesn't work:

```
import polars as pl
df.with_columns([
                (pl.col('old_col').apply(lambda x: func(x)).alias("new_col"),
            ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polars uses [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) functions meaning that they don't have any side effects nor mutably change `self`.

This property will ensure that you can safely pass a `DataFrame` to another function without being afraid that that function changes the state of the `DataFrame` underneath of you.

If you want to change the assigned variable, simply reassign the new state:

```py
df = df.with_column(...)
```